T-SQL select records where each matches certain criteria
I'm using the following table:
CREATE TABLE [GroupTaskMembers]
(
    [GroupTaskId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [MemberId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CompletedAt] [datetime2](7) NULL
)

Sample data:



GroupTaskId
MemberId
StartedAt
CompletedAt




GroupA
Member1
2024-01-15
2024-01-16


GroupA
Member2
2024-01-15
NULL


GroupB
Member3
2024-01-16
2024-01-17


GroupB
Member4
2024-01-16
2024-01-18


GroupC
Member5
2024-01-17
2024-01-19


GroupD
Member5
2024-01-17
NULL


GroupD
Member6
2024-01-17
2024-01-18


GroupD
Member7
2024-01-17
2024-01-18



I need to be able to select count (GroupTaskId) where ALL Members completed the task (i.e. CompletedAt is not null for each MemberId with the same GroupTaskId)
Using the example data above, the expected output would be: GroupB, GroupC. Only one member of GroupA completed the task, so it should not qualify. Similarly, in GroupC, only 2 out of 3 members completed the task as aprt of that group. Member5 completed the task, but as part of GroupC and not D, therefore D does not qualify.
A user can be a member of multiple groups, but what matters if everyone in that group completed the task as part of that group.
So if I do this:
select GroupTaskId 
from GroupTaskMembers 
where CompletedAt is not null

I get a list of GroupTaskIDs where at least 1 member completed the task, but I need to be able to select only groups where ALL members completed the task.
Based on the comments below, particularly the one from Dai, it does seem like "Relational division" is the right approach here, but after spending several days studying it, I am still not sure how to apply it to get the desired result.

What you're looking for is called "Relational division". A quick-and-dirty way to do it is with COUNT( CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 END ) = COUNT(*) within an aggregation group.

how can we know how many people are in one group?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

RDBMSes are set-based systems so another way to do it is with the EXCEPT set operator. e.g.: db<>fiddle.

some data example and expected result would be helpful

Is there a guarantee that a MemberId never appears more than once for any given GroupTaskId? If so, how is it enforced?

@Dai - Thank you, your suggestion seems to point me in the right direction, but I am still not able to figure out how to apply it to get the desired result.
Added sample data per suggestion above.
A given MemberId can only show up once within a single GroupTaskId, but can repeat across groups. It's enforced on the application side, but for the purpose of this problem, let's assume it's always enforced correctly.

Just as Dai commented:
select GroupTaskId,cnt=count(*)
from GroupTaskMembers 
group by GroupTaskId
having count(*)=count(CompletedAt)

count([columnA]) does not increase when columnA is null, but count(*) does

You can run the following Query to retrieve the list of GroupTaskId Which is completed by all members(on the GroupTaskMembers table)
SELECT
    GroupTaskId
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        GroupTaskId ,
        MemberId
    FROM
        GroupTaskMembers
    WHERE
        CompletedAt IS NOT NULL) A
GROUP BY
    GroupTaskId
HAVING
    count(*) = (
    SELECT
        count(DISTINCT MemberId)
    FROM
        GroupTaskMembers b)

